Как связать Donate Alerts с сервером на Flask
Прописал сервер на Python (Flask), вынес его в общий доступ через ngrok
Создал вебхук с перенаправлением на сервер, сервер работает стабильно
Прописал вывод уведомлений на html


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Donation History</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Donation History</h1>
  <ul>
    {% for donation in donations %}
      <li>{{ donation.username }} donated {{ donation.amount }} {{ donation.currency }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
</body>
</html>



Вопрос в чем, как мне сделать так, чтобы при донате через ссылку доната, уведомления приходили на сервер, и выводились в консоле?
from flask import Flask, request, render_template, jsonify
import requests

app = Flask(__name__)

WEBHOOK_TOKEN = "NBTHl3k4UmGmbEvBA5fz"

API_TOKEN = "9lkU43zWlg11cMVIK6GYdPTLVoysGt6ICpv7FCnn"

API_URL = "https://api.donationalerts.com/v1/donations"

donations = []

@app.route('/donation', methods=['POST'])
def donation_webhook():
data = request.get_json()

if data.get('token') != WEBHOOK_TOKEN:
    return jsonify({'error': 'Invalid token'}), 401

# Получение данных о донате из API
donation_id = data['donation_id']
response = requests.get(f"{API_URL}/{donation_id}", headers={'Authorization': f'Bearer {API_TOKEN}'})

if response.status_code == 200:
    donation_data = response.json()
    amount = donation_data['amount']
    currency = donation_data['currency']
    username = donation_data['username']

    donations.append({
        'username': username,
        'amount': amount,
        'currency': currency
    })

    print(f"Получен донат от {username}: {amount} {currency}")

    return jsonify({'success': True}), 200
else:
    return jsonify({'error': 'Donation not found'}), 404

@app.route('/')
def index():
return render_template('index.html', donations=donations)

if __name__ == '__main__':
app.run(debug=True)


